# Add id number to background image

Tags: jquery

I have the following, i wish to change the backorund image of a div depending on its id.

So far i have this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();


$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5,#b6,#b7').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text'+this.id.substr(-1)).fadeIn(800);
    $('#b'+this.id.substr(-1)).css('background-image', 'url('site_images/05/over_'+'this.id.substr(-1)'+'.png'')')


});
});
```

It all seem to work apart from

```
.css('background-image', 'url('site_images/05/over_'+'this.id.substr(-1)'+'.png'')')
```

Comment: The syntaxic coloration should help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quote problems.

```
$('#b'+this.id.substr(-1)).css(
    'background-image', 'url("site_images/05/over_'+this.id.substr(-1)+'.png")'
);
```

Note that keeping it simpler helps :

```
var num = this.id.substr(-1);
$('#b'+num).css(
    'background-image', 'url("site_images/05/over_'+num+'.png")'
);
```

Comment: That's not escaping, you simply replaced them with double quotes :)

Comment: Note the indentation : bugs are easier to avoid or spot when the code is easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes:

```
'url("site_images/05/over_'+this.id.substr(-1)+'.png")'
```